# Toast not working in Service

Tags: java, android

I try to create my first Service, of course without success. But this app successfully compiled and not give any error in AndroidMonitor.
In short, buttons no react for pressing.
I added to Android Manifest required line:

```
<service android:name=".MyService"></service>
```

**ClientActivity**

```
package com.example.servicetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btnStartService;
    private Button btnStopService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartService);
        btnStopService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopService);
        initButtonsOnClick();
    }

    private void initButtonsOnClick() {
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnStartService:
                        startMyService();
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnStopService:
                        stopMyService();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(listener);
        btnStopService.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    private void startMyService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    private void stopMyService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
package com.example.servicetest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private Toast toast;
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your service is still working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    private void writeToLogs(String message) {
        Log.d("HelloServices", message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        writeToLogs("Called onCreate() method.");
        timer = new Timer();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        writeToLogs("Called onStartCommand() methond");
        clearTimerSchedule();
        initTask();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 4 * 1000, 4 * 1000);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your service has been started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void clearTimerSchedule() {
        if(timerTask != null) {
            timerTask.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }
    }

    private void initTask() {
        timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        writeToLogs("Called onDestroy() method");
        clearTimerSchedule();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your service has been stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do   `toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Toast** always works with Application's main thread. So you have to be sure that you use thread in main thread.

And still if you want to use Toast in service, then you have to use Handler.

Please check out the below example for Handler in Thread :

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mContext=getApplicationContext();//Get the context here
    }

    //Use this method to show toast
    void showToast(){
        if(mContext != null){
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Display your message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and **it does not provide a user interface.** - from official Android Documentation.

Now as service doesn't have ui, you can not show toast while using service.

Comment: its not true - you can use `Toasts` in `Services` but they have be `show()`n from a UI thread - try to show them from `onStartCommand` for example

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
//        startTimer();
//        sendNotification();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, to wake up every 10 second
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 5000); //
    }

    /**
     * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
     */
    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
//                Log.e("in timer", "in timer ++++  " + (counter++));

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                ""+ (counter++),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
//                Toast.makeText(SensorService.this, ""+ (counter++), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * not needed
     */
    public void stoptimertask() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Use this for button click

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnStartService;
    private Button btnStopService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartService);
        btnStopService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopService);

        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
                startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        });

        btnStopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
                stopService(serviceIntent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: but now is not Service ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       "helllo", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following Code in your Service

```
  if (getActivity()!=null){
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }
```